# Very bad performance on aggegrate group with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this relationship:

`[boards] 1-n [threads] 1-n [posts] n-1 [users]`

Now I want to load all boards, number of threads per board, number per posts per board.

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('boards').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup : {
            from: "threads", 
            localField:"_id", 
            foreignField: "BoardId",
            as: "threads"
        }
    },
    { $unwind : "$threads" },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "posts",
            localField:"threads._id", 
            foreignField: "ThreadId",
            as: "threads.posts"
        }
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            threadCount: { $sum : 1},
            postCount : { $sum: { $size: "$threads.posts" }}
        }
    }
])
```

It is incredible slow. Around 8 seconds (50 boards, 100k threads, 1M posts).
Normally I'd like to load more per query but why is this that slow? Only because the group?

We want to use different collections because of dedicated identifiers and MongoDB does not support unique identifiers for subdocuments.

Comment: Have you had a look at what the [explain functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) can tell you about the query plan, and whether indexing might help?

Comment: @VinceBowdren $group does not use indexes, which I think is the main problem. Because without $group it is quite fast. But how to get this query running faster...and use anything else instead of $group?